# Danger Points and Rank 4 Skills

Tags: 7th-sea-2e

### Relevant Rules

> At **4 Ranks**, you gain the ability to earn 2 raises per set by creating sets of 15, rather than only 1 Raise per set for creating a set of 10.

—Page 146

> The GM may use Danger Points from her pool to:
>
> - Increase the total needed for a Raise by 5 for a Risk or Round.

–Page 177

### The Question

If the GM spends a Danger Point, does that affect the "15 for 2" rule for rank 4 skills? Meaning a set of 20 for 2 Raises? Or does it only affect the normal 10 for 1?

Comment: Since it says "a Raise" it could also mean that the total is raised twice (one for each raise in the pair) so you would pay 15 for 1 or 25 for 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the rule says "increase the total needed" then you get two raises for 20 instead of one for 15.

The game designer has [clarified this point on Twitter](https://twitter.com/wickedthought/status/745307641165996032):

> If the GM uses a Danger Point to increase the TN, you need 20 for 2 Raises.

Comment: This is correct.